# is there a way to do bind particular port on host to container port using docker file

Tags: docker, boot2docker

is there a way to do bind particular port on host to container port using docker file

I have following item in docker file
Step 1 : EXPOSE 8090:8080

but when i run docker run, container binds to port 8080 instead of 8090 as described in docker file.

any idea how i can achieve this using docker file or is there any better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Can't see that docker implements the `EXPOSE` feature as You described it.

From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#expose):

> **EXPOSE**
>
> ```
> EXPOSE <port> [<port>...]
> ```
>
> The `EXPOSE` instructions informs Docker that the container will listen on the specified network ports at runtime. Docker uses this information to interconnect containers using links (see the [Docker User Guide](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks)).

`EXPOSE` isn't an equivalent for the [vagrant `forwarded_port`](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/forwarded_ports.html) functionality.

It's useful when You need to link containers.

If You need to forward a port from the container to the host use the `-p` flag.

Example:

```
docker run -it -p 80:80 5959f94a4d10 /bin/bash
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it makes sense. Port forwarding isn't functionality of container, but rather artifact of how host is customizing. That is probably the reason why DockerFile doesnt' have this construct

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to do bind particular port on host to container port using docker file

No.  The `Dockerfile` is designed to include only *portable* configuration.  Binding to a host port is not portable because the host port may not be available on every system.  These configuration flags may be available at runtime, but are not included in the Dockerfile syntax (and resulting Docker images).

Under the hood, host ports and other non-portable configuration (e.g. volume mounts) are part of the `HostConfig` structure of the container. These are only available at container runtime.